# Delay generating directive until after page is ready and responsive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a single-page app where some parts are really slow. They're slow because I'm displaying 400 complex things in a repeater for the user to scroll through. Each thing is generated by a fairly complex directive that does a ton of data binding and expression evaluation, adds one or two click handlers, and displays a couple of images. In some cases, I also need a `grayscale` CSS filter on those images, but that really seems way too slow.

I have of course already turned most of my data binding into one-time data binding, but simply generating the 400 things for the first time is still slow. It's initially hidden through `ng-if`, which speeds it up when I'm not showing it, but once I do need to show it, everything waits 10 seconds for that to happen. I would like to load it in advance, but using `ng-show` instead of ng-if means the loading of the entire app has to wait for this.

What I would like, is to load the rest of the app, and then, while we wait for user input, start creating these 400 things so they're ready once I need to show them. I don't want the user to notice how slow this is.

Problem is, I have no idea how to do this. Any ideas?

**Edit:** Having thought about this (and discussed this with my wife), I'm seeing two options (that I conceptually understand, at least):

1. The easy, quick, boring and cowardly solution is to simply not show the 400 things at the same time, but cut them in pieces and show 40 at a time. That should make it a lot quicker, but also less nice, as the user needs to click around to access all the data.
2. The interesting solution is to write a new ng-repeat that generates the 400 transcluded copies of the template each in their own asynchronous event, so they don't block user interaction. I really like this idea, but there's one big downside: it's an ambitious idea with deep Angular magic, and I don't have much time available.

Comment: I assume you really meant this is a ONE page single page app (SPA). Regardless, please clarify: "What I would like, is to load the rest of the app, and then, while we wait for user input, start creating these 400 things so they're ready once I need to show them. I don't want the user to notice how slow this is."

Comment: It's a single page app, but there are tabs and other parts in it that are only shown when you click a button. Using `ng-show` means it takes a long time to render on initial load, `ng-if` means it takes a long time to render after the click. I want to delay until after the app has loaded, allowing the user to interact with it without having to wait for a part they may not even use, and yet have it generated and added to the DOM before the user actually clicks the button. Without blocking user interaction for the 10+ seconds it seems to cost to generate the list of 400 things.

Comment: What mechanism do you use to switch between tabs and 'show' them? ng-if/ng-show?

Comment: Yes. With the problems described above. I need something that's kind of in between the two, in which case I'd still need ng-show of course. Maybe delaying the creation of that part of the DOM with a timeout, if that's possible. But even then I think it'd block user interaction. I doubt I could cut the repeater's work into smaller actions.

Comment: And how/when are your populating your array DATA (to trigger the ng-repeat)?

Comment: The data for the 400 things is instantly available. I still need to wait for a smaller amount of server-side data that will determine how to show the things. My plan was to show everything not in that list with a grayscale filter, but that seems unreasonably slow when done 400 times over a complex piece of DOM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130794/discussion-between-momo-and-mcv).

Answer (score 0):

OK, not seeing your code structure, through Q&A, I'm trying to get clarification.  If I understand you correctly, I believe the solution is to process your images asynchronously and remove reliance of creating/processing them on the fly when the view is visible (i.e. via clicking on a button/tab to 'show' the array 'view' and thus triggering the ng-repeat). BTW, this solution assumes the delays are because the images are being **processed** rather than because they are being shown.

**METHOD 1 (less preferred)**
To do this, it's best to create an 'ImageDataService' service, where it get's kicked off at application start, and proceeds with building this array and taking whatever time it needs **asynchronously** without caring what view is showing or not.  This service will be injected into the proper view or directive controller--perhaps where the current ng-repeat scope is.

Meanwhile, you also need to change the directives inside your ng-repeat to get the pre-built data from the array provided by ImageDataService rather than actually doing the calculation at view time. If the data for that directive is not ready, the directive will show something like 'loading...' otherwise, the directive will simply show the prebuilt images. This way, it doesn't matter when ng-repeat is triggered (i.e. its view is showing), because it will just show what are processed and ready at that point and the display the rest as 'loading...'.

**METHOD 2 (I prefer this)**
Alternatively, and maybe better, you can forego creating a pre-processed array in a service as in METHOD 1 and instead modify your directives to process their data asynchronously by invoking a service method that returns an asynchronous promise like this:

(code inside a controller)

```
var promise = ImageDataService.processImage(directiveData);
promise.then(function() {...set the directive image attributes..})
```

Needless to say, the `ImageDataService.processImage()` method needs to return a promise when it is done processing the data.  The directive, as usual, will show 'loading...' until then. Also, although ImageDataService no longer needs to pre-populate its array mentioned in METHOD 1, it might be a good idea to save the processed images to a similar array anyway to serve as cache and not reprocess them needlessly. NOTE, in this case you don't **need** to have processImage() inside a service--but it is really good 'separation of concerns' practice to reserve the work of asynchronous data processing (ajax, etc) within a service which can be injected app-wide rather than within a controller.

Either of these 2 general tacks should work.

Comment: Can you execute directives in a service, separate from the DOM? Because I think the heavy work is mostly dom manipulation and data binding.

Comment: You can have a directive *call* services as described above.  Once the service promise comes back with the processed images, the directive can manipulate the DOM which is mostly 'setting' images (rather than processing them which was already done async in the service).

Comment: There's not a lot of processing on the images themselves, except for the grayscale CSS filter, but I don't think I can offload that to a service, can I? There is some preprocessing for the data that the directive is using, and I suppose I could have a service do that in advance, but I fear most of the work is really the DOM manipulation itself. Though maybe I should check that.

Comment: You need to elaborate what the image processing is. However, here are a few refs that may help:
There are a few ways to see where your app's sluggish.  If you really have one time binding you can verify the number of watchers with an extension called 'Angular Watchers'. Also:
- [Deferring Attribute Interpolation In AJS For Better Performance](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2704-deferring-attribute-interpolation-in-angularjs-for-better-performance.htm)
- [Speeding up AJS with simple optimizations](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135)

Comment: I've got about 1700 watchers at that point. That sounds like it's 4 watchers per item. Without the one-time data binding, it would have been more than a dozen per item, so the first time there's still a lot of data to bind. This data is used to determine two images, several texts, font-sizes, and positions. Then the whole div with everything is scaled by 0.5, and some of the items get a grayscale filter depending on a check whether the user has selected the item. That's one of the watchers I can't eliminate. I'm not sure what the others are. I hope component bindings and ng-click don't count.

Comment: Should of asked this at the beginning--what version of AJS are you using? We had performance issues with AJS below 1.5x and started using the [angular viewport watcher library](https://github.com/wix/angular-viewport-watch) library that is an amazing and extremely simple tool that kills unnecessary watchers in scroll views.  Once we upgraded to 1.5X there was a tremendous performance boost but we kept the 3d party library anyway just in case.  You should look at this handy library.

Comment: I'm using 1.5. I'll definitely look into that library.